# Do (Banach) ultrapowers carry some sort of 'elementary equivalence'?

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, ultrapowers, big-list

The (model-theoretic) ultrapowers had been used for studying elementary equivalnce of first-order structures. Then, they have been adapted to Banach spaces, which are, let me say, second-order creatures. Of course, one cannot expect that all the properties (propositions of the 'language of Banach spaces') can be persevered by ultrapowers. Indeed, an ultrapower of a reflexive space need not be reflexive.

But reflexivity is a somewhat complicated issue. What if we ask easier questions? What properties are preserved by ultrapowers? For instance, suppose that we are given a Banach space $X$ and each its subspace isomorphic to $X$ is complemented. Is such property preserved under ultrapowers?

Comment: The question "What properties are preserved by ultrapowers?" seems overly broad. I don't know the answer to the particular question you give at the end, though. Are you familiar with Heinrich's article *Ultraproducts in Banach space theory*, J. Reine Angew. Math. 313 (1980), 72--104?

Comment: Yes, I am. Of course, I am asking about reasonable but non-trivial properties.

Comment: In keeping with one of MO's guidelines, I really think it would be helpful if you could suggest some of these reasonable but non-trivial properties. "Is **this** true?" is an easier question to answer well than "What kinds of thing might be true?"

Comment: Juris gives good advice in his answer.  As for your specific question, "suppose that we are given a Banach space X and each its subspace isomorphic to X is complemented. Is such property preserved under ultrapowers?", the answer is yes because Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri proved that such an X is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Bill: I thought that the LT result referred to spaces for which every subspace is complemented, and not those for which only the subspaces isomorphic to the original are complemented?

Comment: Please note $c_0$ has also this property.

Comment: Sorry; I misread the question. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say that a Banach space $X$ has property $K$ (for Kummers) provided every subspace of $X$ that is isomorphic to $X$ is complemented.  The classical separable, infinite dimensional spaces that have property $K$ include $\ell_2$, $c_0$, and $\ell_2 \oplus c_0$; the first obviously, the second because $c_0$ is separably injective, and the last is not hard to show. It is known that $\ell_p$  for $1\le p \not= 2 < \infty$ does not have property $K$,  and it is not hard to show that other possible examples, such as $\ell_2(c_0)$ and $c_0(\ell_2)$, fail property $K$. Ultrapowers of $\ell_2$ of course have property $K$. I don't know about ultrapowers of $c_0$. Are they all injective (which clearly implies property $K$)?  Probably not, but I did not try to check the literature.

However, every (complex) HI space [Gowers-Maurey] is not isomorphic to any proper subspace and hence has property $K$. Some real HI spaces have the same property.  Now there are HI spaces that contain uniformly complemented copies of $\ell_1^n$ for all $n$. Probably the original Gowers-Maurey space has this property, but, as Thomas Schlumprecht pointed out to me, it is clear that the HI space $AD$ of Argyros-Delyiani does, and $AD$ has property $K$.  Since $\ell_1$ is a dual space, there is an  ultrapower $Y$ of $AD$ that contains complemented copies of $\ell_1$ and hence $Y$ is isomorphic to $Y \oplus \ell_1$.  But $\ell_1$ contains an uncomplemented copy of $\ell_1$ [Bourgain] and hence $Y$ contains an uncomplemented copy of itself.

Therefore property $K$ is not preserved under ultrapowers.

Comment: A wonderful answer. Unfortunately, the above-mentioned property for $\ell_2\oplus c_0$ is not clear to me...

Comment: If $X$ is a subspace of $\ell_2 \oplus c_0$ that is isomorphic to $\ell_2$, then, since the projection onto $c_0$ is strictly singular when restricted to $X$, the projection onto $\ell_2$ is an isomorphism on some finite codimensional subspace of $X$. On the other hand, if $Y$ is subspace of $\ell_2 \oplus c_0$ that is isomorphic to $c_0$, then the projection onto $\ell_2$ is compact on $Y$.  Play with these two facts to see that $X + Y$ is complemented (note that it is automatically closed by the two facts since e.g. the intersection of $X$ and $Y$ must be finite dimensional; in fact,...).

Comment: ...the sum of any two totally incomparable closed subspaces of any Banach space is closed.

Comment: Let me point out that ultraproducts of Banach spaces are never injective (unless finite-dimensional); see http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/66sub.pdf Theorem 6.1

Answer (score 6):

There is currently a great deal of activity in answering your question. The subject is called "continuous logic" and you can learn quite a bit more about it by searching through the work of Ward Henson or Itai Ben Yaacov. The article [Model theory for metric structures, based on continuous logic][1]http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~henson/cfo/UCLA09text.pdf might be good place to start. But if you are specifically interested in Banach spaces, perhaps the work of David Sherman is a better starting point.